# http 404 , resource not found

Tags: tomcat, http-status-code-404

working with tomcat 6.0  server , i recently get the following problem , i created a jsp , restarted a server , then requesting this page i get the 404 error

```
HTTP 404 the requested resource can not be found.
```

in tomcat folder , the jsp exist , how to explain this , i created another page , same problem
someone told me that this can be caused with summer time wich is changed automotycally by windows .. i don't know , 
have you any idea ?

also things added to existing page , are not displayed (example i added an h1 , to an existing page , it is not displayed ) it is like changes are not applied

Comment: What's the folder structure? Where's your webapp deployed?

Comment: Can u please specify some code where actually the access thing is being done...??

Comment: @NilsH folder i'm pages are directly under the project root

Comment: @HirenPandya , all pages are accessible , but the recently created

Comment: What is the URL that you are hitting ?

Comment: @AbdullahShaikh this my url http://localhost:8080/GRH/gestionConges2/planificateur/congesAnneEncours.jsp

Comment: So do you have GRH application in your tomcat webapps folder ? and then appropriate folder as per the url ?

Comment: I am not sure about the issue, but HTTP 404 is when resource does not exists.

Comment: yes this what confuses me

Comment: Guess. Do you have multiple tomcat installations ?

Comment: i have tomcat 6.0 , and myeclipse tomcat

Comment: If you are running from Eclipse then do a Clean/Publish on Tomcat server

Comment: where i will find this functionality

Comment: what do clean or publish do exacly ?

Comment: @fatiDev *Publish* basically means **deploying** web app to the Tomcat instance configured in Eclipse. Also read the Eclipse wiki here: [What does Publish do for Tomcat servers in the Servers view?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#What_does_Publish_do_for_Tomcat_servers_in_the_Servers_view.3F). For the *Clean* read the official Eclipse documentation here: [Clean projects published on the server](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user/topics/tclean.html)